# Swift image blur

Tags: ios, swift

I could be completely googling the wrong thing however I am trying to achieve this effect when images don't fit the required aspect ratio/dimensions. However, if the image is of size and doesn't require resizing, then this effect is not necessary. It's seen on the majority of large social medias, especially in stories.

[image: Source: Google]

---

*Source: Google Images*

Is there a library or code that mimics this sort of behaviour?

Comment: Why do you need a library? You just display an image twice (two `UIImageView`) with different `contentMode` and adding a blur (`CIImage` filter, probably `CIGaussianBlur`) to one of them.

Comment: @Sulthan I was more wondering if there was an efficient method of doing this, especially since blurring images can be quite taxing on the CPU.

Comment: I don't think so there is such library exist for such purpose though I would also suggest you to go with two image view and make back one scale to fill and second one to aspect fit to get desire result.

Comment: @HarryJ, don't worry about the CPU – `CoreImage` [filters](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/index.html) uses the GPU.

Answer (score 2):

"Normally" i would say, this  is the solution:

...but  *sigh* unfortunately - and i have no idea why - the .fit does not work anymore as i tested it (just could test on 13.2) and it does not (!) show the whole picture but with .filled) ( to test it you have to insert a portrait photo, which is bigger than the screen to see my effect)

or shouldn't .fit show the whole picture? Am i wrong!?

```
struct ContentView: View {

    var name : String

    var body: some View {

        ZStack {

            Image(self.name)
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFill()
                .blur(radius: 15)


            Image(self.name)
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably also a black overlay with alpha would be needed in between.

Answer (score 0):

The traditional UIKit solution is creating your own control view. Following is @IBDesignable and @IBInspectable class BlurImageView subclass of UIView. Create a file with name BlurImageView.swift and add following code to it. In storyboard in your view controller add an UIVIew and change its custom class using identity inspector to BlurImageView. Set image and you are all set.

```
@IBDesignable
class BlurImageView: UIView {

    private var backgroundImageView: UIImageView!
    private var foregroundImageView: UIImageView!

    private lazy var blurEffectView: UIVisualEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIVisualEffect())

    @IBInspectable
    public var alphaForBlurEffect: CGFloat = 0.7 {
        didSet {
            applyBlur()
        }
    }

    public var blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .regular) {
        didSet {
            applyBlur()
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable
    public var image: UIImage? {
        set {
            backgroundImageView.image = newValue
            foregroundImageView.image = newValue
        }
        get {
            return foregroundImageView.image
        }
    }

    // MARK: Initilisation
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupImages()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setupImages()
    }

    private func createBlurEffectView() -> UIVisualEffectView {

        // create effect
        let effectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)

        // set boundry and alpha
        effectView.frame = self.bounds
        effectView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        effectView.alpha = alphaForBlurEffect

        return effectView
    }

    fileprivate func addImageView() -> UIImageView {
        let imageView = UIImageView(frame: self.bounds)
        imageView.clipsToBounds = true
        self.addSubview(imageView)
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        imageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        imageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor).isActive = true
        imageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

        return imageView
    }

    private func setupImages() {

        self.clipsToBounds = true

        // Setup background view
        backgroundImageView = addImageView()
        backgroundImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        applyBlur()

        // setup foreground view
        foregroundImageView = addImageView()
        foregroundImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

    }

    private func applyBlur() {
        blurEffectView.removeFromSuperview()

        // generate new view
        blurEffectView = createBlurEffectView()

        backgroundImageView.addSubview(blurEffectView)
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is SwiftUI solution inline with the one mentioned by [Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8457280/chris)

I tested it using Xcode 11.2 and iOS 13.2. 
Note: I did not include the two test images named "VRectImage" and "HRectImage".

```
struct BlurImageView: View {
    let name = "VRectImage" // "VRectImage"

    var body: some View {

        ZStack {

            Image(self.name)
            .resizable()
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
            .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
            .clipped()
            .blur(radius: 15)


            Image(self.name)
            .resizable()
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
            .frame(width: 300, height: 300)

        }
        .clipped()

    }
}
```

Comment: no, this is not a solution because the image should be on the whole screen, not just 300x300 -  maybe with geometryreader it could make sense....

Comment: The images in the original question are not whole screen.
If it has to be whole screen then remove .frame and .clipped modifiers from the background blur Image view and remove .resizable and .frame modifiers from the foreground Image view.

Comment: ok, then give me a working(!) example where the blurred view (background) is whole screen size and the picture above is as big as it can be that you can see the whole image (.fit) with right aspect ratio. I got this working too, but if i then change the device on iPhone X from portrait to landscape, i have a bottom - spacing :( . But yeah, you are right, with fixed frame the solution is easy.

Comment: @Chris, the above is working code. I tried and shared only when I see it working. :-)